# Проверка используется ли файл

Tags: php, jquery

Как при помощи PHP или JQUERY проверить открыт файл или нет, то есть используется файл где-то еще или нет?

Нужно сделать скрипт, который будет записывать данные в файл циклом, но только когда файл не занят другим приложением.

Comment: Ну разве что попробовать открыть его эксклюзивно... если файл уже открыт, эта попытка должна провалиться.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно смотреть в сторону функции **flock()**

Подробнее об этом: *http://www.php.su/flock()*